# chart.js - Axis lables

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to figure out how to create some custom axis lables for my data.   Im trying to plot time series data.  Im using an XY scatter graph to do this.  My data collection may be irregular..

My time is recorded as Unix Epoch time.  ( ms after 1 Jan 1970 ).   I'd like to be able to put human readable dates/times on the x axis.  rather than display the epoch time.    How would this be best approached?

http://6phrweatherstation.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to add the custom tick callback. 
You can go through this in the chartjs documentation. Here have a look: [link](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats).

The callback provides you the value of each label. You can edit it and return the edited value.

```
function renderChart(data, labels) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'scatter',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: '48 Hours Pressure History HPa',
                data: data,
                borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            },
            ]
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                callback: function(value) {
                  return new Date(value).getDate() +"-"+ new Date(value).getMonth() + "-"+new Date(value).getFullYear();
                }
              }
            }]
          }
        }
    });
}
```